# Find all functions $f:[0;1]\rightarrow[0;1]$ which satisfying the following conditions: $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$ $f(x+y)-f(x)=f(x)-f(x-y)$

Tags: functions, contest-math, functional-equations

Find all functions $f:[0;1]\rightarrow[0;1]$  which satisfying the following conditions: $f(0)=0, f(1)=1$
$$f(x+y)-f(x)=f(x)-f(x-y)$$
for any $x,y\ge0$ such that $(x-y), (x+y) \in [0;1]$.

#### My work so far:

Let $x=y$. Then $$f(2x)=2f(x)$$ for $0\le x \le \frac12$

Let $y=2x, y=3x,...$. Then $$f(nx)=nf(x)$$ for $0\le x \le \frac1n$

**Edit:** This is an IMO1986 Longlisted problem (FIN 1)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From $f(nx)=nf(x)$ you get $1=f(1)=n f(\frac1n)$, so $f(\frac1n)=\frac1n$. Then $f(\frac{m}{n})=m f(\frac1n)=\frac{m}{n}$ for all $0<m<n$. So $f(x)=x$ for all rational $0<x<1$.

This gives $f(x)=x$ for all real $0\leq x \leq 1$ if $f$ is strictly increasing.

To prove $f$ is (non-strictly) increasing (i.e. $a>b \implies f(a) \geq f(b)$, ), we substitute $z=x+y$, $t=x-y$ and assume $z+t\leq1$. Then $f(z)+f(t)=2f(\frac12(z+t))=f(z+t)$, so if $a>b$ then let $z=b$ and $t=a-b$, then $$f(a)=f(b)+f(a-b) \geq f(b)$$

Now note that $f(c)=0$ for some $c>0$, then $f(d)=0$ for all $0<d<c$. Take any reciprocal of an integer $\frac1q$ such that $0<q<c$, then and by using $f(nx)=nf(x)$ we get $f(1)=f(q \frac1q)=q f(\frac1q)=0$, contradiction. So we get in fact that $f(x)>0$ for $x>0$, so $$f(a)=f(b)+f(a-b) > f(b)$$

And hence is $f$ strictly increasing.

Comment: can you prove $f$ is continuous?

Comment: @DeepSea I thought that was given, only realized that it wasn't when I already posted the answer. I'm trying that now.

Comment: @DeepSea I can prove it is strictly increasing, which is also sufficient.

Comment: @wythagoras Could you tell me why $f(a-b)>0$?

Comment: @Wore I missed that, thank you. Clearly $f(a-b)\geq 0$, because of the domain, but I forget to note that $f(0)$ is the only point where the function is zero.

Comment: @wythagoras Why is it that $f(c)=0$ for some $c>0$ implies $f(d)=0$ for all $0<d<c$?

Comment: @Wore Because $f$ is non-strictly increasing and $f(0)=f(c)=0$, so it must also be zero between $0$ and $c$.

Comment: @wythagoras I didn't understand what you said. Why do you say $f$ is non-strictly increasing? The whole point is that it is strictly increasing, however you are using the fact that I asked before to prove it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/44267/discussion-between-wythagoras-and-wore).

Answer (score 4):

Picking up essential points from @wythagoras: For $x,y,x+y\in [0,1]$ the functional equation gives
$$ 2f \left( \frac{x+y}{2} \right) = f(x+y) + f(0) = f(x)+f(y) $$
and $f(0)=0$ shows that
$$ f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$$
$f\geq 0$ implies that $f$ is monotone increasing. Iterating we get $1=f(1)=n f(1/n)$ and then $f(k/n)=k/n$ for $0\leq k\leq n$, $n\geq 1$. Then for any real $x\in (0,1)$ (and rational q's): $$ x=\sup\{q<x\} \leq f(x) \leq \inf\{q>x\} =x$$
The important point is positivity (or boundedness) of $f$. Without this it is possible to construct other (non-measurable) functions using a Hamel basis of the reals over ${\Bbb Q}$. See:
[Cauchy's Functional equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy's_functional_equation)

Comment: I liked the final reasoning you are using. Could you please explain to me how do you obtain $f(x+y)=f(x)+f(y)$? It is not clear to me how you used the functional equation to conclude this

Comment: $f$ equals  the average of its values on symmetric 'neighbor'-points. And $\frac{x+y}{2} = \frac12 ( (x+y) + 0) = \frac12 ((x)+(y))$. Does this clarify?

Comment: I understand the first sentence, but I still don't see how you get $f(x)+f(y)$ for arbitrary $x,y$.

Comment: Not quite sure where your problem is but if you agree upon $f((a+b)/2)=\frac12 (f(a)+f(b))$ for $0\leq a,b\leq 1$ then you use this on the two ways of writing $(x+y)/2$

Comment: That is exactly the equality that I don't agree on. Sorry if it is too clear but I just don't see it

Comment: The functional equation gives $2f(x)=f(x+y)+f(x-y)$. Then set $a=x+y$ and $b=x-y$.

Comment: I got it now. Thanks!